# Styling notification InboxStyle

Tags: android, notifications

I try to implement an extendable notification and I have used the [InboxStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html) for that.

Based on the following image from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify):

[image: inboxstyle notification]

it should be possible to style the text. In this case make "Google Play" bold.

InboxStyle has only `addLine()` where I can pass a CharSequence. I tried with `Html.fromHtml()` and used some html formatting but I couldn't succeed.

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("title");
inboxStyle.setSummaryText("summarytext");
// fetch push messages
synchronized (mPushMessages) {
    HashMap<String, PushMessage> messages = mPushMessages.get(key);
    if (messages != null) {
        for (Entry<String, PushMessage> msg : messages.entrySet()) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(Html.fromHtml("at least <b>one word</b> should be bold!");
        }
        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        builder.setNumber(messages.size());
    }
}
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You don't need to use `fromHtml`. I've had issues with `fromHtml` in the past (when what you display comes from user, code injection can result in ugly things). Also, I don't like putting formatting elements in `strings.xml` (if you use services for translation, they might screw up your HTML tags).

The `addLine` method, as most methods to set text in notifications (`setTicker`, `setContentInfo`, `setContentTitle`, etc.) take a `CharSequence` as parameter.

So you can pass a `Spannable`. Let's say you want "**Bold** this and *italic* that.", you can format it this way (of course don't hardcode positions):

```
Spannable sb = new SpannableString("Bold this and italic that.");
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), 14, 20, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
inboxStyle.addLine(sb);
```

Now if you need to build string dynamically with localized strings, like "Today is **[DAY]**, good morning!", put string with a placeholder in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="notification_line_format">Today is %1$s, good morning!</string>
```

Then format this way:

```
String today = "Sunday";
String lineFormat = context.getString(R.string.notification_line_format);
int lineParamStartPos = lineFormat.indexOf("%1$s");
if (lineParamStartPos < 0) {
  throw new InvalidParameterException("Something's wrong with your string! LINT could have caught that.");
}
String lineFormatted = context.getString(R.string.notification_line_format, today);

Spannable sb = new SpannableString(lineFormatted);
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), lineParamStartPos, lineParamStartPos + today.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
inboxStyle.addLine(sb);
```

You'll get "Today is **Sunday**, good morning!", and as far as I know it works with all versions of Android.

Answer (score 7):

Your code worked like a charm on my Samsung S3 with Android 4.1.1 on it. What Android version are you using?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int ID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        inboxStyle.addLine(Html
                .fromHtml("<i>italic</i> <b>bold</b> text works"));
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        mBuilder.setNumber(1);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using stock Android 4.2.1 (now 4.2.2)

Comment: That's interesting. So what result do you have using edited Activity sample code above? Tried it with Android 4.2 emulator. It works too.

Comment: I could dig deeper and have found the issue on my side: I only wanted to style one part of the message meaning I used `fromHtml()` only on one part of the string. I used `fromHtml("<b>bold</b>") + " some other text"` and the result was no styling. Moving the rest string into the `fromHtml()` call works flawless! Thanks!

Comment: fromHtml() has many drawbacks. Check solution below, I think it's more  robust.

Answer (score 7):

I have made helper method for this:

```
private final StyleSpan mBoldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

private SpannableString makeNotificationLine(String title, String text) {
    final SpannableString spannableString;
    if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
        spannableString = new SpannableString(String.format("%s  %s", title, text));
        spannableString.setSpan(mBoldSpan, 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    } else {
        spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    }
    return spannableString;
}
```

Use like this:

```
inboxStyle.addLine(makeNotificationLine("UserXYZ", "How are you?"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the most simple solution

*It does not use `InboxStyle` because I did not need it in my case*

---

```
CharSequence boldUsernameMessage = Html.fromHtml("<b>@" + username +"</b> " + message);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setContentText(boldUsernameMessage)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(boldUsernameMessage)) // Makes it expandable to show the message
    .build();
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: when the notification is not expanded, the username mikemilla is not bold. How to show mikemilla as bold? When I expand mikemilla is bold, which is fine.

Answer (score 2):

For bold text you should use `<strong>` tag. There is nothing wrong with your code. Just change `<b>` into `<strong>`.

Edit:
You should change your code to this:

```
NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("title");
inboxStyle.setSummaryText("summarytext");
// fetch push messages
synchronized (mPushMessages) {
    HashMap<String, PushMessage> messages = mPushMessages.get(key);
    if (messages != null) {
        for (Entry<String, PushMessage> msg : messages.entrySet()) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(Html.fromHtml("at least <strong>one word</strong> should be bold!");
        }
        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        builder.setNumber(messages.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your answer complete? Seems vital parts are missing

Comment: I do not want to copy and paste you code here. Just changing <b>one word</b> to <strong>one word</strong> should do the thing. I am updating my answer now.