# New Notification Count Popup on App Icon

Tags: java, notifications, android-notifications, android

im trying to make an application where you get a notification every time you press a button. Now, I'v already figured out how to make a notification come in your status bar. But, I also want to show a red popup circle with a number in it on my app icon: Somewhat like this:[A message icon with a red popup circle 2 on the top right corner](http://www.appsfinder.fr/images/android/icons/ICON_17597_1.png)

I'd like to know the android code for doing this. Is it already a built in feature of the SDK or do i have to do something else? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Notification number that is count as below:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.number = <Your Notification Count here>; // int value
```

Update `Notification.number` everytime when user presses a button

If you want a reference code Please check this [open Source](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

Comment: Yeah. That is deprecated. Instead, you can use `notification.setnumber(6)`.. Pls check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setNumber%28int%29

Comment: It shows a number in the notification bar but no red popup next to the launcher icon on the home screen.

Comment: You can use a plugin instead... Please check this link: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: You can check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602072/styling-notification-inboxstyle as well... Please use `Notification Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry, you can't badge your app icon the way you're asking. Notifications are the recommended and only way to communicate this kind of information to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method by passing context and count value , which create an circle on app icon and displays the count number

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", this.getClass().getName());
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```