# Android use BOLD text in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

i have notification in application and i want to have some bold text into that.i'm try to use `Html.fromHtml()` that not working correctly. for example:

1)

```
Spannable sb = new SpannableString ( mContactName );
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan (android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

contentView.setTextViewText(sb );
notification.contentView = contentView;
```

2)

```
contentView.setTextViewText(Html.fromHtml ( "<![CDATA[ <b>" + mContactName + " </b> ]]>"  ));
```

this ways dont work. now how to have bold text? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `fromHtml`.

The `addLine` method, as most methods to set text in notifications (`setTicker`, `setContentInfo`, `setContentTitle`, etc.) take a `CharSequence` as parameter.

for more details, please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602072/styling-notification-inboxstyle/21661375#21661375).