# How to bold text in a notification

Tags: java, android

I currently have a notification that displays the sender and the message they sent. I would like to display the name in bold but am struggling to do so. Does anyone know how?

```
Html.fromHtml(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "<b>%s</b>", wrappedName))
```

This is what I am currently using and is not working.

Comment: Have you tried `"<strong>%s</strong>"`?

Comment: add notification code to better help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually it's better use InboxStyle than HTML parts.

```
Spannable sb = new SpannableString("Bold text");
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder()
     .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
         .addLine(str1)
         .addLine(sb);
         .setContentTitle("")
         .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
     .build();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

Just use this line of code to get bold text in your notification.

```
Html.fromHtml(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "<strong>%s</strong>", wrappedName));
```

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` is old HTML. Use `<strong>` newer HTML tag for bold text(HTML5).

There is a better way that you can achieve this without using `formHtml`, refer this: [Styling notification InboxStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602072/styling-notification-inboxstyle/21661375#21661375) and [this Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html).