# Android API 28 Notification Title not bold when in Hebrew

Tags: android, android-notifications

I show a notification like this:

```
 val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_care)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.welcome_notification_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.welcome_notification_body))
            .setColor(Color.BLUE)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 300)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(getString(R.string.welcome_notification_body)))
        val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(Intent())

        val intent = Intent()

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build())
```

I'm using Hebrew text. It works great. Only in API 27, the title of the notification is bold, as it should be, and as is with all notifications.

But in API 28 the title isn't bold, and it's hard to tell the difference between the title and the message. This only happens when the title is in Hebrew text, with English it works fine.

How can I fix this so that the title will always be bold?

Thanks

Comment: This link might help [Title Notification Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593710/how-to-bold-text-in-a-notification)

Comment: The formatting of the title is handled by the firmware. By default, on Android 9.0, the title is bold (tested on a Google Pixel 2). Perhaps your device manufacturer changed the behavior on your particular device.

Comment: I've edited question, it only happens with hebrew text

Comment: If it's related to the language then it's likely related to the font. Does this happen on all devices or just devices from a particular manufacturer? The notification font is set in the system theme, so it's either Google's default font, or overridden by the manufacturer.